# Wrong filter on string field length in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch dsl in python. I want to filter my documents setting minimum length of string field. My code:

```
s = es_dsl.Search(using=es, index='some_index')
s = s.filter('exists', field='message')
s = s.filter('script', script=f"doc['message.keyword']?.values.toString().length() >= 50")
s = s.source(['message'])
s.scan().__next__().to_dict()
```

But I've found that one document with length more than 50 symbols didn't return.
Document that was ignored:

```
{'message': 'На днях со мной произошло удивительное событие.<...>Прекрасный удивительный заморский мир!\n\nВ Украине должно быть тоже так.'}
```

If i change filter from 50 to 2 symbols it returns, but with higher threshold - no. Does it make any sense?

Comment: This script would be really long. You should add a length field and index it.

Comment: + please join us the document you found.

Comment: i have updated text of question

Comment: Can you try with no russia (i thinck it is) character ?

Comment: With other russian texts works fine

Comment: You really should add a size field for perforance reason. If you still want to use a script, try to loop on your string and count yourself the number of iteration. For obscur reason in your exemple, it s seems length return the first word size instead of the total field size. Can you edit your mappings too?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps